# Button click not working in a panel post back in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application which requires a warning message to be displayed first - which needs to be accepted by the user and then requests for the credentials.
So, here is what I did -
I have one form with 2 panels - 1) warning with Accept button and 2) login with login button.
On page load I set the visibility property, panel 1 visible = true and panel 2 visible = false.
On Accept button click, toggle the visibility of the panels - panel 2 visible = true and panel 1 visible = false.
Enter the credentials and click Login for user authentication and enter the application.

The approach works fine in the local host but not on the  server.
It throws "XML parsing error: no element found" error in FF and a blank page in IE and chrome on the first button click.

*Edit Code snippet*

```
<script runat="server">
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (method.Authenticate(user.Text, pass.Text))
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Text, true);
    else
        Panelwarning.Visible = true;
        Msg.Text = "Login failed";
        PanelLogin.Visible =false; 
}

public void btnAcpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{  
    PanelLogin.Visible =true;
    Panelwarning.Visible = false;
}  

public void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    PanelLogin.Visible =false;
    Panelwarning.Visible = true;
}
</script>   

<form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <asp:Panel ID="Panelwarning" runat="server" >
         <p  class ="ex1"> Warning message</p>
         <div align="center">
         <asp:Button ID="IAcceptButton" runat="Server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnAcpt_Click" onmouseout="this.className='button'" onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhover'"  Text="I Accept" />         
         </div>   
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="PanelLogin" runat="server">
        <fieldset>
            <h4> login information goes here</h4>
            <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="Server" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" onmouseout="this.className='button'" onmouseover="this.className='button buttonhover'" Text="Login"/>
        </fieldset>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Web.config

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" debug="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="/Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Edit 2
Found out that forms authentication is causing the issue. When the first post happens, it is intercepting for the form submission - which I do not want.

Comment: I'd say it's on line 32... Just kidding. We can't really tell you what the problem is without you showing us what the code is doing. It would be great if you could present this as a [mcve].

Comment: Post your `aspx` and `codebehind`, and `web.config` as well.

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited with code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Since no code is provided it's difficult to determine the error's cause. Take a look at this thread where it is said that invalid characters on URL (if you're using parameters) could be the origin:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1004395.aspx?What+causes+this+XML+Parsing+Error+no+element+found

**UPDATE**

You're missing the braces `{}` on the `else` clause:

```
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (method.Authenticate(user.Text, pass.Text))
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(user.Text, true);
        else
        { // <-- Missing
            Panelwarning.Visible = true;
            Msg.Text = "Login failed";
            PanelLogin.Visible =false; 
        } // <-- Missing
    }
```

Comment: Since is working on Dev enviorement then the issue could be an IIS configuration or even folder rights, as mentioned in this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226003/xml-parsing-error-no-element-found

Comment: I would also check the Event Viewer on the server for more details about the error.

Comment: And check for unclosed tags in your `aspx` and `web.config` files:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-resolve-xml-parsing-error-no-element-found